# IntelliJ Idea 14 keyboard works weird on mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, cursor, intellij-14, keymaps

Earlier I could delete a selected text with delete key in my mac. Now I have to delete it using "shift" + "delete"."delete" deosn't work anymore

Also when I selected a text and delete it, I cannot use arrow keys to move the cursor. It keeps selecting the texts while I move the cursor. I cannot type anything also. I have to press esc key and exit select mode and then type. Also while I'm typing if I press esc key, the cursor turns to a block. Then I cannot type anything. But all the character keys does some weird stuff. Like goes to the bottom of the file.

When I press the key "s", the cursor turns back to the "|" and I can type again.
Please give me some advise. I already tried changing the keymaps, restarting the keymaps, Completely cleaning intellij and reinstalling.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I figured it out. Vim emulator is the one giving problems. You can disable vim emulator in Tools menu. Then the keyboard works normally.